# Show that function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f$ : $[a, b] \rightarrow\mathbb C$ be continuous.

Show that the function 
$F : \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C $ defined by $$ F(z) = \int_a^b f(t)\exp(tz) dt$$ is holomorphic.

I am unsure of how to start, I think I should get some property of holomorphic functions like composition or integral of holomorphic functions is holomorphic but I'm not sure if any such thing exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to observe that$$\int_a^bf(t)\exp(tz)\,\mathrm dt=\int_a^bf(t)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^nz^n}{n!}\,\mathrm dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\int_a^b\frac{f(t)t^n}{n!}\,\mathrm dt\right)z^n.$$

Comment: So we can say that as it is analytic, it's holomorphic right. And why can we interchange summation and integral in this, there is some restriction on it I suppose?

Comment: @johndoe We can interchange it because the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).

Let $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb C$ be a closed piecewise $C^1$ path. Then

$\displaystyle
\int_\gamma F(z)\,dz
=\int_0^1 F(\gamma(s))\gamma'(s)\,ds
$

$\displaystyle
=\int_0^1 \int_a^b f(t)\exp(t\gamma(s))\,dt\, \gamma'(s) \,ds
$

$\displaystyle
=\int_a^b \int_0^1 f(t)\exp(t\gamma(s))\gamma'(s) \,ds\, \,dt
$

$\displaystyle
=\int_a^b 0 \,dt = 0
$

The switch in the order of integration is ok because the integrand is continuous and the domain is compact.

The last inner integral is
$\displaystyle
\int_\gamma f(t) \exp(tz)\,dz
$
and so is zero by Cauchy's theorem, since the integrand is a holomorphic function for fixed $t$.